# Error building syntaxnet using Dockerfile

Tags: docker, syntaxnet, docker-build, parsey-mcparseface

I built using the docker file - [Dockerfile](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/syntaxnet/Dockerfile) . It runs for two hours. However, in the end it shows -

Executed 0 out of 17 tests: 17 were skipped.

I assume the docker build is not getting executed correctly as I am also unable to do -

> echo 'Bob brought the pizza to Alice.' | syntaxnet/demo.sh

which again results in an error. 
Has anyone else also faced the same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I made a Docker file by myself because I couldnt find a proper file for it, Its a little more complex but i recommend you to do it by your self so you can control all packages versions.
[Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/569) check the Docker file at the end of the issue, hope it helps.